# VS Code: How to assign an existing SSH key

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-keys

I already set up an SSH key and it's located in it's original folder `C:\Users\Username\.ssh`. The key works perfectly fine when I try to push commits onto a repository from the console, however once I attempt to do the same from Visual Studio, it tells me I don't have the correct authorization.

How can I let Visual Code use my already existing and working SSH key?